# Does CDN cache get cleaned before cache-control(s-maxage) in firebase hosting?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cache-control, firebase-hosting

This is the cache control I set for my cloud function endpoint which is actually served through firebase hosting -

cache-control: public, max-age=1296000, s-maxage=1296000

I can even see this in the response headers of the api call. So I assume the cdn cache settings are set right.
If I try to make the api calls few hours apart to the same endpoint, I get the x-cache: HIT as well.

But when I try it after 2-3 days, I get X-cache: MISS and it seems to fetch from the origin. Even though the age is set to 15 days (as above), I am not sure why this is happening.
The app is currently in development so I am the only one making the api call. I just wanted to know if the edge doesn't get any api calls, does the cache get cleared even before s-maxage?

Comment: Did you `firebase deploy` to hosting any time before the 15 days are over?

Comment: No I particularly waited for 2 days without any new deployments and checked it but still got X-cache: MISS

Comment: @DougStevenson Just a quick question. If the url has different query params and I am setting the cache-control based on query params, they should still have different cache times isn't it? So https://url?episode=all has cache-control of 2 days and https://url?episode=1 has cache-control of 15 days. Is this a valid pattern to set?